# Regarding Python on Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

How do you manually stop a Python script running on Visual Studio Code?

I am on Mac. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using a terminal, if so then press ctrl+c to stop a script. If taht doesn't work try ctrl+z. These commands should stop any terminal program.

Comment: `CTRL+Z` stops the process, but you should add that it puts it into background as a stopped job, it does not kill it.

Comment: killall python would do the next thing.

Comment: @harsimarriar96: dangerous!

Comment: Could you please elaborate @cdarke.

Comment: @harsimarriar96: other processes, including some system ones, could be using python that this could kill.

Answer (score 1):

For quitting the process and terminating from background aswell. Use `CTRL+\`

You can stop the interactive python by using `CTRL+D`.

For stopping python scripts use `CTRL+Z`. (Process won't be terminated though. Use killall for that.)

To terminate all python scripts running in background. Run `killall python` or `sudo killall python`. *Run with caution*

And to stop other scripts use `CTRL+C`

Comment: `CTRL+D ` on macOS only stops interactive python, it sends EOF.  It has no effect on a python script unless reading from `stdin`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, didn't knew it. Updating the answer. :)